Mysql SUM inside Left Join return wrong value when using with rollup function
Good Afternoon.
I have some problem/missunderstood with rollup function when using LEFT Join statement. the sum from rollup function at the end is not like my expected. please see the sample table data from my table
***tb_no_penjualan***

id_no_jual | total_bayar  | created_date
----------------------------------------------
2         | 1024176.00   | 2024-10-23 20:40:10
3         | 520000.00    | 2024-10-23 20:47:39
4         | 241000.00    | 2024-10-23 20:55:26
7         | 346280.00    | 2024-10-24 08:55:22
8         | 957840.00    | 2024-10-24 08:57:49
9         | 534064.00    | 2024-10-24 09:04:32
12        | 731864.00    | 2024-10-24 09:34:06

***tb_det_jual***

id_det_jual | id_no_jual | jumlah_item | total_harga
-----------------------------------------------------
2           | 2          | 2           | 300000.00
3           | 2          | 2           | 50000.00
4           | 3          | 25          | 237500.00
5           | 4          | 2           | 331500.00
6           | 7          | 1           | 150000.00
7           | 7          | 5           | 252200.00
8           | 7          | 5           | 50000.00
9           | 7          | 5           | 100000.00
10          | 7          | 2           | 329800.00
11          | 8          | 3           | 494700.00
12          | 9          | 4           | 201760.00
13          | 12         | 3           | 494700.00
14          | 12         | 5           | 50000.00
15          | 12         | 7           | 140000.00

i have try to use this query
SELECT a.id_no_jual,
       date(a.created_date) as tanggal,
       SUM(a.jumlah) as jumlah_item,
       SUM(a.total_harga) AS total_harga,b.total_bayar 
from pos.tb_det_jual a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_no_jual as id_no_jual, 
                   SUM(total_bayar) as total_bayar 
            FROM pos.tb_no_penjualan 
            group by date(created_date) ) as b ON(a.id_no_jual=b.id_no_jual)
group by date(a.created_date) WITH ROLLUP;

and the result from that query like this:
id_no_jual | tanggal   | jumlah_item | total_harga    | total_bayar
---------------------------------------------------------------
2          |2024-10-23 | 31          | 919000.00      | 1107280.00
7          |2024-10-24 | 40          | 2263160.00     | 2620739.20
7          |Null       | 71 (correct)| 3182160.00(ok) | 2620739.20 (wrong)

the result i wanted like this:
id_no_jual | tanggal   | jumlah_item | total_harga    | total_bayar
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2          |2024-10-23 | 31          | 919000.00      | 1107280.00
7          |2024-10-24 | 40          | 2263160.00     | 2620739.20
7          |Null       | 71 (correct)| 3182160.00(ok) | 3728019.20

is any mistake from my query? please correct the query if i wrong,
Regards.

please add the correct result that you want to have , because is don't know what byar means

Test does GROUP BY 2 WITH ROLLUP produces the same output? Additionally - enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and aggregate a.id_no_jual.

dear nbk, i've already edit my expected result. thank you

dear Akina,
after enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, i've got error like this, Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pos.c.nm_lokasi' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is a.id_no_jual supposed to be functionally dependent on date(a.created_date)? It sounds a bit peculiar but without the definition of what keys you have, it's hard to tell.

hello lennart, Yup correct. a.id_no_jual dependent on date(a.created_date). But now i know the answer from another threads on Stackoverflow.
thank you.
